# How do I declare a class attribute as a union of class names?

Tags: raku

I'm reading a spreadsheet looking for different structures. When I tried the following using Moose it seems to do what I want. I could create different types of objects, assign this to the found member
and dump the Cell instance for review.

```
package Cell
{
  use Moose;
  use Moose::Util::TypeConstraints;
  use namespace::autoclean;

  has 'str_val'    => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', required => 1 );
  has 'x_id'       => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', ); # later required => 1 );
  has 'color'      => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', );
  has 'border'     => ( is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', );
  has 'found'      => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Sch_Symbol|Chip_Symbol|Net', );
  1;
}
```

If I try to do the same in Perl 6 it fails to compile.

```
class Cell {
  has Str $.str_val              is required;
  has Str $.x_id                 is required;
  has Str $.color;
  has Str $.border;
  has Sch_Symbol|Chip_Symbol|Net $.found is rw
}
```

> ```
> Malformed has
> at C:\Users\Johan\Documents/moose_sch_3.pl6:38
> ------>   has Sch_Symbol'<'HERE'>'|Chip_Symbol|Net $.found is rw
> ```

How can I do this in Perl 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`where`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature#index-entry-where_clause_%28Signature%29)

```perl6
has $.found is rw where Sch_Symbol|Chip_Symbol|Net;
```

or define new type by [`subset`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/typesystem#subset)

```perl6
subset Stuff where Sch_Symbol|Chip_Symbol|Net;

class Cell {
    has Str   $.str_val is required;
    has Str   $.x_id    is required;
    has Str   $.color;
    has Str   $.border;
    has Stuff $.found   is rw;
}
```

Comment: As Brad notes, a common role will always be faster. It'll also often be more appropriate than a `subset`/`where` due to its different separation of concerns. If you declare a `Common` role then all you have to do is declare your classes with a `does Common`. Or even skip that and just append `but Common` to objects that need to pass a `Common` typecheck. In contrast a `subset`/`where` has to be modified for each class you want included. If it's a `subset` in a module you `use`, you need a *new* subset of the old one (so slower still) and you have to switch the constraint to the new name.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want them to do a common role and specify that as the type

```perl6
role Common {}
class Sch-Symbol does Common {…}
…

class Cell {
  …
  has Common $.found is rw;
}
```

---

Or you will have to use a `where` constraint

```perl6
class Cell {
  …
  has $.found is rw where Sch-Symbol|Chip-Symbol|Net;
}
```

You could also create a subset to wrap the `where` constraint.

```perl6
subset Common of Any where Sch-Symbol|Chip-Symbol|Net;

class Cell {
  …
  has Common $.found is rw;
}
```

Note that a `where` constraint is slower than using a common role.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fully working implementation of the `subset/where` solution mentioned by Brad Gilbert in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49660766/215487). This includes one example for each of the classes in `Common` and also one example that shows what happens when type constraints aren't met:

```
#!/bin/env perl6

class  Sch-Symbol { has Str $.name }
class Chip-Symbol { has Num $.num  }
class         Net { has Int $.id   }

subset Common of Any where Sch-Symbol|Chip-Symbol|Net;

class Cell {
  has Str $.str_val  is required;
  has Str $.x_id     is required;
  has Str $.color;
  has Str $.border;
  has Common $.found is rw;
}

my $str_val = 'foo';
my $x_id    = 'bar';

my @founds = (
    Net.new(:42id),                 # will work
    Sch-Symbol.new(:name<baz>),     # will work
    Chip-Symbol.new(num => 1E101),  # will work
    42,                             # won't work
);

for @founds -> $found {
   my $cell =  Cell.new(:$str_val, :$x_id, :$found);
   dd $cell;
}
```

Assuming this is in the file `test.p6`, when we run `perl6 test.p6` we get:

> ```
> Cell $cell = Cell.new(str_val => "foo", x_id => "bar", color => Str, border => Str, found => Net.new(id => 42))
> Cell $cell = Cell.new(str_val => "foo", x_id => "bar", color => Str, border => Str, found => Sch-Symbol.new(name => "baz"))
> Cell $cell = Cell.new(str_val => "foo", x_id => "bar", color => Str, border => Str, found => Chip-Symbol.new(num => 1e+101))
> Type check failed in assignment to $!found; expected Common but got Int (42)
>   in submethod BUILDALL at test.p6 line 9
>   in block <unit> at test.p6 line 28
> ```