# How do you declare a sum type/type union?

Tags: types, porting, raku

This works:

```
use v5;
use Moops;
class Foo {}
class Bar {}
class Example :ro {
    has some_attr => isa => ArrayRef[
        # http://p3rl.org/Type::Tiny#Overloading
        #                 ↓
        InstanceOf['Foo'] | InstanceOf['Bar']
    ];
}
my $e = Example->new(some_attr => [Foo->new, Bar->new]);
```

Attempt:

```
use v6;
class Foo {}
class Bar {}
class Example {
    has Foo|Bar @some-attr; # ???
}
my $e = Example.new(some-attr => (Foo.new, Bar.new));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I declare a class attribute as a union of class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660447/how-do-i-declare-a-class-attribute-as-a-union-of-class-names)

Comment: Also note that you can declare the subset inside of the class if you want — it just won't be available to anyone else

Comment: I've just added [a comment at the previous SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49660447/how-do-i-declare-a-class-attribute-as-a-union-of-class-names#comment106067230_49660933) in which I advocate the use of a role rather than a subset/where. (I'm commenting here to bring my new comment in that SO to your attention.)